# Collapse navbar on navigate (link click) in mobile mode

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I'm using bootstrap 3 with angular. When I click a link the page isn't reloaded, causing the menu to stay open when in mobile mode.

**How do I make the menu close automatically when I click a menu item?**

I have tried just adding  `data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse"` to the `a` tags, but it causes strange behavior in desktop mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the angular directive I ended up using.
There's a couple of things to watch out for.

- Don't collapse the menu when in desktop mode (look for overflow-y == auto)
- Handle menu state when resizing window with an open menu that closes when the window grows.

I use the ic-nav-autoclose directive on the element with the nav class.

---

```
angular.module('incmn')
    .directive('icNavAutoclose', function () {
        console.log("icNavAutoclose");
        return function (scope, elm, attrs) {
            var collapsible = $(elm).find(".navbar-collapse");
            var visible = false;

            collapsible.on("show.bs.collapse", function () {
                visible = true;
            });

            collapsible.on("hide.bs.collapse", function () {
                visible = false;
            });

            $(elm).find("a").each(function (index, element) {
                $(element).click(function (e) {
                    if (visible && "auto" == collapsible.css("overflow-y")) {
                        collapsible.collapse("hide");
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Nice. I was looking for something on the lines of this.

Comment: Great. Why dont we add a directive directly to navbar-collabse instead of parent element. So we can avoid extra jquery lookup.

Comment: Just in case any one else has had the problem of getting the menu to collapse after changing the page in a single page app, this link shows how to change the 'isCollapsed' variable after the routing has been taken care of: https://www.pointblankdevelopment.com.au/blog/getting-the-bootstrap-3-navbar-and-angularjs-to-play-nicely-together

Answer (score 7):

This is just updated version of previous answer

```
angular.module('app').directive('navCollapse', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var visible = false;

            element.on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
                visible = true;
            });

            element.on("hide.bs.collapse", function () {
                visible = false;
            });

            element.on('click', function(event) {
                if (visible && 'auto' == element.css('overflow-y')) {
                    element.collapse('hide');
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

HTML

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-app-collapse" nav-collapse="">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have done like this.

```
$(selector).click(function () {
  //for close, opened dropdown.
  if ($("nav").hasClass("in")) {
    $('[data-toggle="collapse"]').click();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your navbar to collapse after the next click, no matter where on screen it occurs:

1. Make your `.navbar-toggle` button **only open** the nav:

   ```
   <div class="navbar-header">
       <button class="navbar-toggle" ng-click="collapsed = true">
   </div>
   ```
2. Append `.navbar-collapse` with an invisible full-screen underlay that, when clicked, closes the nav:

   ```
   .invisible-underlay {
       position: fixed;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;
       background-color: transparent;
   }

   <div class="navbar-collapse" collapse="navbarCollapsed" ng-click="navbarCollapsed = true">
       <div class="invisible-underlay"></div>
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
           <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
       </ul>
   </div>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

this code works with dropdown sebmenu in nav bar

```
angular.module('app').directive('navCollapse', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var visible = false;

            element.on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
                visible = true;
            });

            element.on("hide.bs.collapse", function () {
                visible = false;
            });

            element.on('click', function (event) {
                if (visible && 'auto' == element.css('overflow-y') && $(event.target).attr('data-toggle')!="dropdown") {
                    element.collapse('hide');
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```